# If religion worked like Stack Exchange

Tags: religion

There are many gods. They are all immortal and cannot harm each other directly. They rarely interact with each other except for occasional chat. A god's  purpose is to get as many powers and "god-badges" as possible.

Humans can choose freely which god to worship and vote on their miracles etc.

There is an important difference from SE however. All gods' ultimate ambition is to become the One-and-Only deity. They must amass as many worshippers as possible with the idea of attracting the *entire* population of the world whilst maximising their reputation and powers.

Unpopular gods can only perform small miracles. Popular gods get increasing powers according to rules similar to those of Stack Exchange.

To stop things getting out of hand there are impartial Goderators. Their purpose is to make the rules for god behaviour and enforce them.

**Questions**

Given that the Goderators are utterly fair and don't want humanity to suffer too much as a result of the gods fighting amongst themselves, what rules should they draw up to keep the gods in order?

What is the best strategy for a god to become the one and only god?

What strategy would a god with zero followers (and therefore very limited powers) need to employ in order to attract a following.

**Additional facts and differences from Stack Exchange**

Goderators draw up a list of rules for the gods. They cannot stop them from acting but anyone who breaks the rules can have some of their powers or god badges taken away.

A god cannot be banned - the worst that can be done is to remove all their reputation and badges so they must start again.

Goderators can observe the human world but not affect it at all.

Gods are aware of each other but cannot prevent anyone else's miracles or actions. They can form alliances but ultimately they will have to betray these if they are to become the One-and-Only.

Humanity know about the gods and who did which miracle or act of destruction. They vote them up or down in their local temple. The vote is done anonymously in a god-proof cubicle so the gods cannot punish or reward for votes. Humanity does not know about the goderators.

Comment: I think the only thing to do at this point is defer to our local Goderator [Tim B](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b) and Lord Divine [bowlturner](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner). ;)

Comment: This feels like multiple different questions to be honest, it would probably be worth breaking it up into establishing the rules and optimal strategies.

Comment: @TimB - Thanks for your idea. I'm relatively new to SE so I'm not sure how to implement it. Would you suggest having more than one question thread or is it better to reformat the existing question. I'm not entirely sure how that should be done. At the moment I have three questions. Do you mean just combine the last two under a heading?

Comment: FWIW, check our Terry Pratchett's ["Small Gods"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Gods) not so far from what you describe.

Comment: @AdiShavit - Thanks  -  I've always meant to read Pratchett and never got round to it. Maybe I should now :-)

Comment: One important difference: you're describing a zero-sum game (a god wins only by taking away from other gods), which isn't the case on Stack Exchange.  Sure there can be only one Jon Skeet, but the rest of us can still participate. :-)  Anyway, not a complaint but just an observation to take into account.

Comment: I mean that for each question you have create a new question here on stack exchange for it. The simplest way is to edit this down to be the first question and then ask two more. Feel free to cross link between the questions.

Comment: So long as they are all different & on topic you are welcome to ask as many questions as you like :)

Comment: @Frostfyre No points for third place huh? I suspect I'd get a bit darker title around here though.

Comment: @Samuel Can't list everyone, so someone has to get left off the list. Besides, you've got plenty of points already. ;)

Comment: I've closed this as too broad since it's still multiple questions, once it's edited down it will be a great question though so I hope it can be re-opened soon :)